# Styles are not being applied to children props

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native

My container class:

```
import React from 'react';
import {View} from 'react-native';

const Cont = (props) => {

    return(
        <View style={styles.cStyle}>
            {props.children} 
        </View>

    );
};

const styles =  {
    cStyle: {
        borderWidth: 1,
        borderRadius: 2,
        borderColor: '#fff',
        borderBottomWidth: 0,
        elevation: 10,
        marginLeft: 5,
        marginRight: 5,
        marginTop: 10
    }
};

export default Cont;
```

Now the class that uses this component:

```
import React from 'react';
import {Text} from 'react-native';
import Cont from './Cont';

const Det = (props) => {

    return(
        <Cont>
            <Text>{props.alb.title}</Text>
        </Cont>
    );
};

export default Det;
```

I don't think I need to provide the index.js, since all I'm doing related to the subject in matter is calling a self closing tag of the object. I have no idea why my styles are not being applied. I checked everything I thought I could of have checked. Any ideas? Any support is appreciated.

PS: I was expecting `<Text />` childs to inherit my styles

PS2: Also I'm not sure this is really 'inheritance'. Because actually the styles should affect every `<View>` from my class and then consequently the children that is INSIDE my `<View>` tags

Comment: Are you expecting the `<Text/>` child elements to inherit styling in some way ?

Comment: Yeah, thats what I was expecting. Sorry if I wasn't clear on the question

Comment: Try this: const styles = StyleSheet.create({//1
        cStyle: {
         //...
        }
    });

Comment: Also tried using React's default StyleSheet function...didn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd like to answer my own question regarding this issue because there might be other persons struggling now or in the future, and would not know quite what to do, hopefully this answer will help them.

There was no error in my code, at least not in the classes I posted above. And EVERY `<Text>` children should be inside a styled `<View>`, which was my intention at first. So I had made a typo when calling the class in the entry js file. But, somehow (yes this defies my current React Native knowledge which is already little) the app was still compiling but not styling ANYTHING. Only after I restarted not only the server in the terminal but also the simulator, is that I received the bug which I could finnally debug. (Unexpected char 'blabla' in Line X). After fixing it my styles were applied. But the craziest thing is: It was either compiling with an unexpected character (which seems impossible to me) or compiling a past version of my App. Now, this sounds absolutely crazy to me and I will be reporting it on React Native forums and Android Studio. Thanks for all the help.

EDIT: React Native forums topic on the issue: http://discuss.nativebase.io/t/android-simulator-compiling-wrong-code/1183

Answer (score 0):

Regular styles behave differently in `react-native` compared to CSS in say, the web-browser. There's no concept of style inheritance by default in `react-native`, so styling that you apply to `<Cont />` won't be inherited by the children of `<Cont />` (ie your `<Text>` elements).

When styling with react, you'll typically need to apply styles directly to all components that you want to tweak the appearance of:

```
<Cont>
    { /* custom styling must be applied to all components that you 
         want to tweak */ }
    <Text style={{ color : 'red' }}>{props.alb.title}</Text>
</Cont>
```

Something to also keep in mind is that different element types (`<Text/>` , `<View />`, etc) sometimes only support a limited subset of styling options. For example, [see the styling documentation for `<Text />`](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/text#style) for an overview of the styling options that the `<Text />` element type supports.

Comment: This is very strange to me. I tried to do the same thing but actually add the style to Cont. It also didn't work...

Comment: Btw I just tried to style Text directly in the same way. Also didn't work! =(

Comment: Yes it is a little strange at first - also something to keep in mind is that some styles don't have any affect on certain elements like `<Text/>`. react-native is great, but it's situations like this that you realise it's not equivalent to react-js/web development

Comment: Also I'm not sure this is really 'inheritance'. Because actually the styles should affect every <View> from my class and then consequently the children that is INSIDE my <View> tags. Right?

Comment: You need to apply styles on a per-component basis. If you wanted to share the `styles.cStyle` with `<Text>{props.alb.title}</Text>`, then you could do so by this : `<Text style={styles.cStyle}>{props.alb.title}</Text>`